# Creating a list of location names from Google geocoding API in R

Tags: json, r, for-loop, rcurl, google-geocoding-api

I'm new to R and am having trouble with a for loop I wrote to create a list of location names from a list of zipcodes I have using the Google geocoding API. This is an example based on what I have so far:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)

zips <- c("10001", "10002", "10003","10004","10005","10006")

test <- NULL  
temp <- NULL  
for (i in 1:length(zips)) {
    temp[i] = fromJSON(getURL(paste('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=', zips, sep="")))
    test[i] <- temp$results[[1]]$formatted_address
    Sys.sleep (.3) #Google limits your API calls to 5 per second.
}
```

Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: If you create `temp[i]`, you need to call it after: `temp[i]$results[[1]]$formatted_address`. Why don't you simply store your request in `temp`, rather than in `temp[i]`?

Comment: You might want to consider using the `revgeocode ` function in the `ggmap` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you were missing an [i] subset to read through the zips. 
This should work:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)

zips <- c("10001", "10002", "10003","10004","10005","10006")

tmp <- NULL
test <- vector("character", length(zips))
for (i in 1:length(zips)) {
    tmp <- fromJSON(getURL(paste('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=', zips[i], sep="")))
    test[i] <- tmp$results[[1]]$formatted_address
    Sys.sleep (.3) #Google limits your API calls to 5 per second.
}

print(test)  

## [1] "New York, NY 10001, USA" "New York, NY 10002, USA" "New York, NY 10003, USA"
## [4] "New York, NY 10004, USA" "New York, NY 10005, USA" "New York, NY 10006, USA"
```